# Adding ajax loading gif to script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Thanks for looking, I have the below script that updates a series of drop down boxes, populated depending on the users previous answer. Data comes from SQL tables. I was wondering how I could add an Ajax loading gif to each drop down while the data is loading. I hope this makes sense, if not please ask.

```
<script language="javascript">
var xmlhttp

function selectmanu()
{

xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
  return;
  }
 document.form1.mtype.style.background = "#FFFFFF"
 var id=document.form1.mtype.value;


var url="selectmanu.php";
url=url+"?id="+id;
/*url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();*/
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
  document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}


function selectmodel()
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
  return;
  }
  document.form1.manu.style.background = "#FFFFFF"
 var id=document.form1.manu.value;
var url="selectmodel.php";
url=url+"?id="+id;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged1;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged1()
{

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
  document.getElementById("modspan").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

function validate()
{

if(document.form1.mtype.value=='0')
{
document.form1.mtype.style.background = "#FF0000"
return false;
}
else if(document.form1.manu.value=='0')
{
document.form1.manu.style.background = "#FF0000"
return false;
}
else if(document.form1.model.value=='0')
{
document.form1.model.style.background = "#FF0000"
return false;
}
return true;
}
function mset()
{
if(document.form1.model.value!='0')
{
document.form1.model.style.background = "#FFFFFF"
}

}

</script>
```

Cheers,
B.

Comment: This is beside the point but are you aware that with a JS-library such as jQuery, you could simplify the above JS to pretty much 5-10 lines?

Comment: I wasn't - JS isnot my bag - I got a friend to do this for me. Thanks though. Do you think that what I'm asking is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of images, you could disable the "select" and put a single "option" with a loading message. You do that before the XHR call.

```
<select disabled="">
  <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

Once you get your data, replace this "option" by the real ones, and remove the attribute "disabled".

Visually it is ok, and users do not have anything to guess.

Comment: Good amn for answering - not sure how this fits in though

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have images in select options, but I'm too sure. Don't quote me on that.

Nevertheless, it should just be a case of having an `onChange` JavaScript function that replaces the next `select` element with a loading image whilst querying the database for your options. When the options have been retrieved by AJAX, replace the loading image with a select field, and loop through your AJAX response and add an `option` tag for each option you retrieved from the database.

As mentioned above, libraries like jQuery make writing functions like this easier, but for that you do need a good knowledge of writing JavaScript from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: all of the functions I posted above work using onChange, is there a way of incorperating them within the functions already done?